# How to control FEA software like MSC NASTRAN using Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, system

I would like to run MSC NASTRAN using python. I have seen a similiar function in MATLAB using
`system('nastran.exe file_name.bdf')` #where file_name.bdf is the input file to Run using nastran.

Hence i tried below using python code, but it did not work,

```
import os
os.system('nastran.exe file_name.bdf')
```

Could you tell me where i going wrong?

Also, how to give the command line in NASTRAN thru python? Like for example memory allocation for the run, number of cores need to be used for run etc.

some NASTRAN command lines include,
1. scr=yes delete=f04,log,xdb pause=yes
2. mem=10gb bpool=3gb memorymaximum=14gb sscr=500gb sdball=500gb mode=i8
...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak directly for MSC Nastran, its been a while since I've used it. But most modern FEA programs have an API (application program interface) to allow you to call commands from a external program like python or matlab.

Without an API, you may be limited to using python to start the program from the command line, which is what your code is trying to do. As for how to launch a program from within python, check out this question/answer:
[How to run application with parameters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032212/how-to-run-application-with-parameters-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to run a MSC NASTRAN file is to create a .bat file and run it from python.
The format for .bat file is:

```
<nastran.exe location> <Python script file location> <Nastran command line>
```

An example can be :

```
C:\MSC.Software\MSC_Nastran\20141\bin\nastran.exe C:\py_nastran_run\example.bdf scr=yes old=no delete=f04,log,xdb
```

Then include the below line in python script,

```
status=subprocess.call("runBatch.bat")
```