# Using bash to glue python and c++

Tags: python, bash

I have a c++ executable that performs a simulation and would like to use this simulation as my function for an optimization routine. My idea is to implement the optimization routine in python and glue python and the c++ executable together using a bash script.

Is this possible? Are there other approaches I should consider?

I have looked at creating a python extension module but the c++ project is large and I believe it will take far too long to implement this.

Comment: I believe boost.python does what you want (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/index.html). Also try searching a bit this question has been asked a bunch on here.

Comment: any particular reason your python script can't run the c++ executable directly?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen` in Python to interact with external code via stdin/stdout. If you communicate via files, use `subprocess.run` and read the result.

Comment: @xception the executable is currently run from the terminal with some flags required to run, can this be done via python?

Comment: absolutely can be done from python, and most programming languages I ever used, have a look at this question for how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032212/how-to-run-application-with-parameters-in-python

Comment: also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output/4760517#4760517 to see how you can get the output of a command you run directly from python

Comment: @xception thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible - I have done it my self outputting the value of the onjective function to the terminal and parsing the output in python, calling the simulation as subprocess. Note that this can even be interfaced to batch submission systems if your simulations runs a long time. However, having a proper python interface only for the simulation function might be better - I can recommend https://github.com/pybind/pybind11 as an alternative to boost here.